# function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]

Tags: c, pointers

I am working on a simple program that will grab the memory address of a given variable upto 64 bits(unsigned long). currently this is the code I have but for someo reason the compiler is throwing me warnings saying that my method is returning address of a local variable when that is what I have intended.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 char* one = argv[1];
 long memaddress = address(one);
}

uint64_t address( char * strin)
{
        return (uint64_t) &strin;
}
```

How would I alleviate this warning and what could be causing this warning to come up?

Comment: This is to little for a function, why don;t you go for a MACRO?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Never use a macro where a function will work. But that one is nonsense as either.

Comment: @Olaf so what are you suggesting to do? I plan on implementing more to the address function but i kept it as simple as possible for asking a question. How would i have the address be passed to the main?

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_. And your code invokes undefined behaviour on dereferencing. It does not make much sense is bad style. Also `long` is not guaranteed to hold a pointer.

Comment: @WasabiCannon: As you don't give enough information, I just can specilate you have an XY problem. Whatever that is supposed to be, it is bad code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can imagine the function definition and its call

```
long address = address(one);
//...
uint64_t address( char * strin)
{
        return (uint64_t) &strin;
}
```

the following way

```
long address = address(one);
//...
uint64_t address( void )
{
        char * strin = one;
        return (uint64_t) &strin;
}
```

As you see variable `strin` is a local variable of the function. It will be destroyed after exiting the function. Thus its address after exiting the function will be invalid. And the compiler warns you about this.

To avoid the warning you could write the function at least the following way

```
uint64_t address( char ** strin)
{
        return (uint64_t) &*strin;
}
```

and call it like

```
long address = address(&one);
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `strin` is local to the `address` function and *ceases to exist* when `address` returns, making the pointer value invalid in the `main` function, hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

`strin` is a pointer that is passed by value in `address`.

You are essentially trying to return the address of that, albeit cast into a different type.

But the address of `strin` will no longer be valid once the function exits, and your friendly compiler is warning you of that.

The solution is to use a `void*` as an address, not some type designed for something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the variable into the function, it creates a copy of the variable and passes it to the function you call as a local variable. If you return the address of this variable, you'll be getting the location of the local variable *for the function you're returning from*. That is, you won't be getting the location of the `one` variable but of `strin`, in this example.